# Facebook like button in iPhone native app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to implement facebook like button in my native iphone app. So that user can like my facebook page  . I am already sharing facebook status updates, but am unable to implement like button.

I was unable to find any helpful resource on web.***Please help.***

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding the Facebook Like Button in an iPhone App](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2783803/adding-the-facebook-like-button-in-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

Aaaand here's one I prepared earlier (using FBConnect, the FB api):
If you have the id of the post as `postId`

```
NSString *graphPath = [[NSString alloc] 
                                       initWithFormat:@"%@/likes",
                                       postId];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:graphPath andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

of course you'd need to change how you got the Facebook singleton (I used [delegate Facebook]).

Comment: And if you aren't using the FBConnect api... I can't help.

Comment: This may be used to like `posts` but not URLs or Pages

Comment: Ahhh, oh well. My bad. Should I delete the answer?